# Regeneration of database in yii

Tags: yii, model, migration, phpdoc

I am a newbie to yii. I have lost my database, I only have models, controllers and views. Can I systematically regenerate database using models, please?

Comment: You should have migrations in your app to restore database schema. If you don't have these, most likely you will not be able to do this automatically.

Comment: I have migrations but its not covering all database files, approximately its only 25% of the total database